# How to pull data from root level site and display in subsite using JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, jsom, site

I have a custom list on root level site in SharePoint Online. I want to display the list data to one of my subsite pages.

I am using JSOM. How can I achieve this?

Following is my code which gets the data from the current site. But I want to fetch it from the root level site.

```
context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the root site url as shown below:

```
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl;
```

Get client context using that url as shown below:

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 6):

This could help

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();         
var web = context.get_web();                        
var parentInfo = web.get_parentWeb();   
var parentWeb = context.get_site().openWebById(parentInfo.get_id());

context.load(parentInfo); context.load(parentWeb);
```

Answer (score 4):

By using the following code you can get the root web :

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.oSite = clientContext.get_site();
this.oWebsite = this.oSite.get_rootWeb();
clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);
clientContext.load(this.oSite);
```